# Email address masking

Tags: postfix

I would like to mask/alias the email addresses of my customers behind my own domain(ex: custid@mydomain.com) such that any third party (that is allowed to contact them) cannot get their real email addresses. I also want to ensure that the customer is not aware of his alias on my server. Hence when the email is finally delivered to the customer, the *to* address will have to be his real address and not the alias.

How can I accomplish this with postfix?

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve here? It's highly unlikely you'll be able to solve this without a significant amount of custom development. What have you tried this far?

Comment: So, I can see that `canonical` could be used to rewrite your `custid@mydomain.com` to `name@example.com` though I'm not sure if you could that will prevent `Delivered` headers from giving the game away.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create an implementation of what's called in jargon an [anonymous remailer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_remailer) which is non-trivial to do well and probably impossible with just stock postfix.

Answer (score 1):

smtp_generic_maps might help here. It would not be completely transparent for your customer, though.

Have you had a look to http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html ?